# How to find the least used or longest unused packages in Debian based Linux distributions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I would like to get rid of some packages that I have seldom used or not used in a very long time. I am particularly interested in how to list such packages via command-line tools like `dpkg`, `apt-get` or `apt-cache`, but it would be good if someone could also list ways of doing it via GUI programs such as Synaptic. Is it possible to query packages based on usage statistics or date of last use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There isn't such a tool. 
You can list all installed packages

```
dpkg-query -l
```

The tool `deborphan` (`sudo apt-get install deborphan`)
can help you to find orphaned packages in specific categories like interpreters, data, common or in all categories. To list all possible orphaned packages:

```
sudo deborphan --guess-data-all
```

append text to upper commandline to remove those packages with the configuration files.

```
| xargs -n1 sudo apt-get purge
```

---

A GUI version of this tool should be available (haven't tried).

```
sudo apt-get install gtkorphan
```